# How to find out programatically that your facebook App got banned

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk, facebook-fql

I have a facebook App that for some reason it got banned.
How can I find out programatically (FB C# SDK preferably) at login for instance that the application got banned?

There are no exceptions or other markers that I noticed so I could figure out this.
I am open to any ideas.

The app is not doing anything un-ethical but it pulls up a lot of data and there is a possibility that FB might not like that. So in order to keep it live, I want to know when the app got banned so that i can replace it on the fly with another one, until the issue gets resolved with th first one. FB gives you an answer only after 2+ weeks.

Comment: I think if your FB app getting banned warrants being notified programatically then perhaps you have bigger potentially ethical issues that are more impending than your technical issues.

Comment: Perhaps but I still need an answer...

Comment: The point @maple_shaft is making is that if you have a likely ethical issue to address, many of use will have an ethical responsibility to know the outcome before we can provide a work around.

Comment: "Doc, it hurts when I do this." "Then stop doing that."

Comment: The app is not doing anything un-ethical but it pulls up a lot of data and there is a possibility that FB might not like that. So in order to keep it live, I want to know when the app got banned so that i can replace it on the fly with another one, until the issue gets resolved with th first one. FB gives you an answer only after 2+ weeks.

Comment: I once wrote a Dropbox App where I could see the status of the App and whether it was approved/declined. Maybe you as the developer have something similar on a Facebook console, too?

Answer (score 2):

You *might* be able to use the `installable` field in the `properties` array from admin.getAppProperties outlined here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/admin.getAppProperties/

Comment: 10x for the answer , I'll try that.